# Javascript array of strings won't convert to array of integers

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have an array of strings (eg: "0","1","10") that I want to convert to an array of integers.  However, my array is not changing.  I confirmed that pre and post conversion the array elements still hold strings.  Can someone explain why and how to fix this?

```
for(var i=0; i<mydata.length;i++) {
    console.log("Pre type ["+i+"] is "+typeof(mydata[i]))
    if (typeof(mydata[i])==="string") {
        mydata[i] = parseInt(mydata[i])
        console.log("Converting element "+i)
    }
    console.log("Post type ["+i+"] is "+typeof(mydata[i]))
}
```

**This code is running in a QML component which has its own Javascript interpreter - QML seems to be critical to this question.**  The debug statements show:

```
qml: Pre type [0] is string 
qml: Converting element 0 
qml: Post type [0] is string
```

Comment: [No repro](https://jsfiddle.net/3gs5w179/) ..?

Comment: That code would work, assuming they are ‘string’ and not ‘String’. Show input which “doesn’t work” and how the output is being used/verified. Since there are many debug statements, what are they indicating?

Comment: FWIW: use a radix — parseInt(x, 10) — unless it is allowed that the numbers are not decimals.

Comment: Very strange but Sascha's suggest of using map to change entire array at once appears to work.  Investigating why...starting to suspect this is QML's javascript interpreter that may have an issue...can someone confirm the above code works ok in a pure JS environment?

Comment: @TSG I doubt QML is somehow ‘that deficient’. Hypotheses 1) usage difference; 2) the original array is “silently immutable”. #2 can be easily verified.

Comment: I'm also thinking it's silently immutable.  I have a QML alias to this array from QML's Settings component, which I suspect is preventing individual elements from being modified but allows complete replacement of the array.

Comment: Test the hypothesis, and add details & answer if this is the case. It may be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go over the array and use **parseInt** on every element of it.

**Note:** As Matt Morgan mentionend (and you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description) it's better to use for parseInt as second parameter the radix of 10 as base for the normal decimal-system.

```js
let arr = ["0","1","10",'17'];

let res = arr.map(el => parseInt(el,10));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is proper code but why would it work when the OP code does not?

Comment: Also, `parseInt` should also be passed a radix I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description

Comment: This answer works so I've accepted.  I should point again (per the original question) that this occurs in QML's javascript interpreter.  NOT in a pure JS browser environment.  So although my original code should have worked (per pure JS), in QML's JS it does not.  But Sascha's response DOES work properly in the QML environment